# Insert elements on top of something without changing visible scrolled content

Tags: javascript, css

I'm building a chat interface for a website. When it first loads, the most recent messages are displayed, with the newest at the bottom, as is common with most chat apps.

As the user scrolls up, more messages are loaded via our API, and inserted above the existing messages.

As you might expect, the chat bubbles are styled `<div>`s inside a container `<div>` that has `overflow-y: auto` and a set height.

Currently what I'm doing is noting the top message `<div>`, loading the older messages above it, and then repositioning the view to try and put the user back to almost where they left off, but it's tricky, especially when the chat bubbles contain dynamically loading elements (embedded images, etc). (I do not know the height of these bubbles before the browser renders them.)

In an ideal world, I would like to find a way to insert the messages above, without causing the scrolled position to move at all, so that the user doesn't lose track of where they are in the stream of messages.

I've never heard of such a thing, but it would be cool if there was a way to tell the div to stretch itself in the upward direction, rather than causing it to push the existing messages down further.

Any advice would be appreciated.

[Here is a JSFiddle that shows the basic problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/cn4ju9ga/3/) It simulates my chat interface, by loading 30 chat messages when the page loads, and then puts you at the bottom of the message list. As you scroll to the top, another 30 are loaded, but you'll see that this is jarring to the UX because you instantly lose your place.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Richard's answer, with a technique based on `requestAnimationFrame` to re-align the viewport. (For my use of it, I utilized the `scrollTop` of my scrollable div, rather than `window.scrollTo` as shown in his example.)

Comment: Could you provide a minimal runnable snippet of your currently working code?

Comment: I guess you just need to take note of scroll position, add the loaded messages and scroll to new loaded messages height + old scroll positon. about images loading: you could send the height/width before loading the image, that way you can size the box beforehand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fortunately, there is. The CSS property is called [`overflow-anchor`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-anchor/). When you set the `overflow-anchor` property of an element to `auto`, it will turn on [scroll anchoring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor/Guide_to_scroll_anchoring); which is an attempt of the browser to minimize the problem of content jumping (such as a large image loaded above your scroll position causing your content to scroll further down); *and* set said element as the potential anchor when adjusting scroll position.

That being said, `overflow-anchor` is automatically set to `auto` and you *needn't set it*, so I'm not sure how setting it manually helped you. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor):

> Scroll anchoring behavior is enabled by default in any browser that supports it. Therefore, changing the value of this property is typically only required if you are experiencing problems with scroll anchoring in a document or part of a document and need to turn the behavior off.

Here's a simple demonstration. At first, the `window` is already scrolled by 200px. Every two seconds, a new `div` is inserted on top of the container. Note that the visible area of the `window` doesn't change even when a new `div` is inserted on top the container.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container')

window.scrollBy(0, 200)

let counter = 9
setInterval(() => {
  let newDiv = document.createElement('div')
  newDiv.classList.add('messages')
  newDiv.innerText = counter++;
  container.prepend(newDiv)
}, 2000)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-anchor: auto;
}

.messages {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #121212;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="messages">8</div>
  <div class="messages">7</div>
  <div class="messages">6</div>
  <div class="messages">5</div>
  <div class="messages">4</div>
  <div class="messages">3</div>
  <div class="messages">2</div>
  <div class="messages">1</div>
</div>
```

---

### Update

As setting `overflow-anchor` manually did help you with adjusting scroll position upon height increase above the viewport, but Safari does not support `overflow-anchor`, here's a simple alternative mechanism (using `requestAnimationFrame`) to adjust the viewport so that it always stays in its current position. This code below also adjusts the scroll position when you are at the **top** of the container and older messages show up (*an issue you mentioned*).

Note that I've set the `overflow-anchor` to `none`, thus disabling the scroll-anchoring browsers usually enable automatically, to show that this code works (I'm running it in Firefox). Also, the code is adjusted such that it does not scroll down when new `messages` are appended to the `container`. *Do consider the scenario when the user is reading the last message and a new message gets sent; you might want to scroll down in that case.* Furthermore, I am calling `getBoundingClientRect()` every frame. If not used properly, this can cause [layout thrashing](https://kellegous.com/j/2013/01/26/layout-performance/) (also read [here](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) for the list of JS properties/methods that can cause this).

One last note: I actually wanted to use `ResizeObserver`, but as Safari does not support that API, I used `rAQ` instead to observe container's height changes. There are already `ResizeObserver` polyfills, which I have not tried out yet, but may be more efficient than using `rAQ` to observe height changes. Here's the [page](https://github.com/WICG/ResizeObserver/issues/3) that contains a lot of links to `ResizeObserver` polyfills.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container')
let counter = 9
setInterval(() => {
  let newDiv = document.createElement('div')
  newDiv.classList.add('messages')
  newDiv.innerText = counter++;
  container.prepend(newDiv)
}, 2000)
window.scrollBy(0, 200)

// Mimicking scroll anchoring behaviour from browser
let previousLastChild = container.lastElementChild
let previousBoundingRect = container.getBoundingClientRect()
function scrollAdjustment() {
  let boundingRect = container.getBoundingClientRect()
  let isHeightIncreased = boundingRect.height !== previousBoundingRect.height
  let isAppend = container.lastElementChild !== previousLastChild // Is height increase caused by new messages being appended?
  if (isHeightIncreased && !isAppend) { // If new messages are appended, don't scroll down as people are reading the upper messages
    let newScrollYPosition = window.scrollY + boundingRect.height - previousBoundingRect.height
    
    previousBoundingRect = boundingRect
    window.scrollTo(0, newScrollYPosition)
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(scrollAdjustment)
}

requestAnimationFrame(scrollAdjustment)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-anchor: none; /* Note I've set it to none */
}

.messages {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #121212;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="messages">8</div>
  <div class="messages">7</div>
  <div class="messages">6</div>
  <div class="messages">5</div>
  <div class="messages">4</div>
  <div class="messages">3</div>
  <div class="messages">2</div>
  <div class="messages">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "and set said element as the potential anchor when adjusting scroll position," since your example shows the property being set on the container, and not one of the elements within the container?

Comment: Downside of this approach is it's not available for Safari at this time.

Comment: @MasonG.Zhwiti "and set said element as the potential anchor when adjusting scroll position". By *said element*, I did mean the `#container`, not the individual `#messages`. `#container` is acting as the anchor for `window`. `window` can then adjust its scroll position based on changes to `#container` viewable region. The scrollbar does not belong to `#container`. It's the `window`'s scrollbar.

Comment: @MasonG.Zhwiti I'm convinced that you can use `IntersectionObserver` to manually do what scroll-anchoring does. I actually wanted to use `ResizeObserver`, but it doesn't seem to be supported in Safari either. I still haven't tried `IntersectionObserver` though.

Comment: I had thought `IntersectionObserver` would be more useful for the infinite-scrolling aspect, i.e. determining when to load more messages as the user scrolls back in time. How were you thinking to use it for scroll anchoring? My current technique (which is not working well) is to note which element is near the top when more are loaded, and then drop down to that point again once the loading is finished, but it's still jarring, especially since it stops the natural scroll decay/slowdown that is usually happening at that point.

Comment: @MasonG.Zhwiti Turns out I was wrong. Sorry, I don't think that I can use `IntersectionObserver` to mimic scroll-anchoring.

Comment: @MasonG.Zhwiti I used `requestAnimationFrame` to observe height changes and adjust scroll position. Do try looking at my updated answer with `overflow-anchor` set to `none`. (You shouldn't set this to `none`, I'm only doing this because I'm running the code in Firefox and it is enabled automatically).

Comment: Wow, this looks amazing, will dig into this today, thank you! FWIW, I agree the initial `overflow-anchor: auto` likely was not doing anything since it is the default setting in browsers that support it.